# Сколько целочисленных решений имеет уравнение x^(y^z)=2^81

Tags: алгоритм, математика

Сколько целочисленных решений имеет уравнение x<sup>y<sup>z</sup></sup> = 2<sup>81</sup>  при y<sup>z</sup> не равном 1?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию.

Answer (score 6):

Много :)

```
2^(3^4)
2^(9^2) 
2^(81^1)    :)
8^(3^3)
8^(27^1)
512^(3^2)
512^(9^1)
(2^27)^(3^1)
```

По просьбам трудящихся :)

Очевидно, что [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Тогда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Понятно, что [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и [image: введите сюда описание изображения], так что получаем [image: введите сюда описание изображения].

Дальше все, по-моему, совершенно очевидно. 8 решений соответствуют

```
   l      k      z
 -------------------
   1      0      4
   1      1      3
   1      2      2
   1      3      1
   2      0      2
   2      2      1
   3      1      1
   4      0      1
```

Comment: перебором? :-) или все-таки какой-то алгоритм?:)

Comment: @Grundy Да все просто. Очевидно, что x = 2^n. Все Получается n*y^z = 81. Очевидно, что n - степень тройки, типа, n = 3^m. Чтобы y^z было не 1, y - тоже степень 3. Дальше рассказывать? :)

Comment: Конечно рассказывать :-) и в ответ это все перенеси ;-) _n*y^z = 81_ эээх, а я тут почему-то вот так считал _n^y^z = 81_ и из-за этого не получалось :)

Answer (score -2):

Два решения, где

x, y, z =

2, 9, 2

2, 3, 4

**UPDATE**

@Grundy указал, что есть и третье решение

2, 81, 1

Comment: А, вообще, 100% оффтопик

Comment: попробуй писать более развернутые ответы. почему только два? `2 81 1` - вполне подходит

Comment: а что тут разворачивать? да и оффтопик. Твой ответ не пришел в голову.

Comment: Разворачивать, очевидно, способ решения. как видишь - ты не угадал с ответом. В принципе могут быть и другие варианты